# rm command fails on files with 777 permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I am trying to delete the file `old.txt`, which is located at:

```
/disks/tests/backend/version/old.txt
```

- `/disks/tests` is a mounted disk
- `/disks/tests/backend` is owned by another user (same group as me) with 777 permissions
- `/disks/tests/backend/version` is owned by me with 777 permissions
- `/disks/tests/backend/version/old.txt` is also owned by me with 777 permissions

When I attempt `rm old.txt`, I get:

```
rm: cannot remove `old.txt': Permission denied
```

I also tried `lsattr old.txt` and I get:

```
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on old.txt
```

Any ideas on how to remove this pesky file? Thanks!

**edit:** please note, I don't have super user privileges.

Comment: is disk mounted rw?

Comment: `ls -l /disks` shows that `/disks/tests` has `rwxrwxr-x` permissions, and I am neither the owner, nor in his/her group. Is that causing my problem?

Comment: what does `mount` say?

Comment: `mount -l` returns `myfs02:/ifs/sw/tests on /disks/tests type nfs (rw,intr,secure,grpid,intr,addr=<censored>)`

Comment: The lsattr error is not surprising, you can't use lsattr or chattr on a file in an NFS mounted partition. So you have to check their attributes from the host machine.